# Как передать часть модели из представления в контроллер?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Я хочу создать представление на котором располагается таблица содержащая коллекцию объектов и форма для добавления новых объектов. После внесения изменений в представлении эти изменения передаются в контроллер, но у меня не получается передать из  представления часть модели, в контроллер передается null. Как это можно исправить?

**Модель**

```
public class Test
{
    public List<string> table1 { get; set; }
    public  List<List<string>> table2 { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {
        table1 = new List<string>() {"", "", ""};
        table2 = new List<List<string>>();
    }
}
```

**Контроллер**

```
    public class TestController : Controller
{
    private Test testModel;

    public TestController(Test testModel)
    {
        this.testModel = testModel;
    }


    // GET: Test
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(testModel);
    }

    public ActionResult AddRow(List<string> list)
    {
        if(list!=null)
            testModel.table2.Add(list);
        else
            testModel.table2.Add(new List<string>(){"fail","fail","fail"});
        return PartialView(testModel);
    }
}
```

**Представление**

```
<div id="editor">
<div>
    @using (@Ajax.BeginForm("AddRow", new AjaxOptions() {UpdateTargetId = "editor"}))
    {
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                @for (int i = 0, cnt = Model.table1.Count; i < cnt; i++)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.table1[i])
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
    }
</div>
<div>
    <table class="table2">
        @for (int i = 0, cnt = Model.table2.Count; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                @for (int j = 0, cnt2 = Model.table2[i].Count; j < cnt2; j++)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.table2[i][j])
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: используйте `ViewBag`

Comment: В представлении происходит изменении части модели (List<string>), и эта измененная часть должна передаться в контроллер. После чего представление частично обновляется. Если я его складываю в ViewBag то я не получу изменения из представления

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо в методе

```
 public ActionResult AddRow(List<string> list)
```

заменить list на table1, тогда вместо null вернется отредактированный список из представления